# Calculating percent of polygon within another polygon using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have two polygon layers, say `A` (`multipolygon`) and `B` (`multipolygon`), and I want to find the percent of `A` in `B`. For example, the percent of one of the `A` polygons with ID `1` will be stored in one of the Polygons in `B` with ID `a` attribute table as two new columns `A` with that polygon's ID `1` and and a second column `Percentage` with the corresponding percentage of that polygon and so on.

Polygon A:

[image]

Polygon B:

[image]

I did find [Determining percent of polygons within other polygons using ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306604).  However, the answer is not super helpful/clear.

How can I do this is ArcGIS Pro 3 without using Python as I am not a Python user? Maybe this could be done in ModelBuilder.

Desired Output with two new columns `A_ID` and `Percentage` added to `B`:

```
B_ID A_ID Percentage 
a    1    X%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Tabulate Intersection](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm) does exactly this.  However, it does require an Advanced license.

> **Summary**
>
> Computes the intersection between two feature classes and
> cross tabulates the area, length, or count of the intersecting
> features.
>
> **Illustration**
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you, so will `A` go in as `input zone features` or `input class features`?

Comment: Can you kindly respond to my comment?

Comment: Depends what you want. B zone, A class, will give you % of B overlapped by A, and A zone, B class, will give you % of A overlapped by B.

Answer (score 2):

As @user2856 mentioned, the ‘Tabulate Intersection’ tool would be the easiest way.  Also, as @champezius mentiond, the Erase tool could also be helpful.  However, these tools both require an advanced license, which is rather costly.

If you don't have an advanced license, then you could use the [Union](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm) tool for this, and then delete the polygons that have an FID_*clipping_feature_class* <> -1.  What ever is left would be the area that you're interested in.

(The Union tool also adds all attributes from both of the input feature classes to the output feature class.)

See Union tool documentation for details:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/union.htm

To actually calculate the percentage, you would have to join your original feature class to the union-output feature class based on the FID (ObjectID) of the original feature class and the FID_*input_feature_class* of the union-output feature class.  Then use the area attribute of both to calculate the difference, or percentage.

Comment: Thank you, so the union tool will also add the two new columns `A-ID` and `Percentage` to polygon `B` or will I have to use a different tool for that?

Comment: The union tool will add all of the attributes from both of the input feature classes to the output feature class.  However, you will still need to do the calculation for percentage as a separate step.  I'll add a bit more to the answer for this...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input polygons always intersect, you can use the [Erase](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/analysis/erase.htm) tool on your polygons - which creates a new feature class. Then you can compare the area of the new feature class with either input polygon.

If you want to do all your analysis in ArcGIS Pro or ModelBuilder then you'd need to add more tools to Calculate the percentages and add new fields - see [Calculate Field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm).